# Como eu transformo um array que esta em uma string para array em javascript?

Tags: javascript, array, string

Eu tenho uma string representando um array da seguinte maneira:

```
var = "['aaaaa', 'bbbbb', 'ccccc', 'ddddd']";
```

Queria poder transforma esse array que esta na string em um Array para realizar manipulações.

```
var = ['aaaaa', 'bbbbb', 'ccccc', 'ddddd'];
```

Obrigada desde já.

Answer (score 7):

Essa string que tens parece um JSON, uma representação em *String* de uma array, e por isso podes usar `JSON.parse()` para a tranformares numa array.

**Há contudo um problema...** `'` não é válido como separador de strings em JSON, por isso não podes usar

```
var arr = JSON.parse("['aaaaa', 'bbbbb', 'ccccc', 'ddddd']");
```

mas sim:

```js
var string = "['aaaaa', 'bbbbb', 'ccccc', 'ddddd']".replace(/'/g, '\"');
var arr = JSON.parse(string);
console.log(arr);
```

Comment: Acredito que fazer `var string = "['aaaaa', 'bbbbb', 'ccccc', 'ddddd']".replace(/\'/g, "\"")` fique um pouco mais simples para o tratamento da *string*.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss essa maneria também é boa. Tenho ideia que passei a usar `split/join` depois de testes onde vi que era mais rápida. Mas neste caso é provavelmente irrelevante. `+1`

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss mudei, a tua sugestão fez-me ir fazer um teste rápido (https://jsfiddle.net/3L5etu88/) e de facto `replace` é bem melhor.

Answer (score 5):

Outra opção é utilizar [Array.prototype.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

```js
var a = "['aaaaa', 'bbbbb', 'ccccc', 'ddddd']";
var array = a.replace(/['\[\] ]/g,'').split(',').map(String);
console.log(array);
```

Se desejar remover o espaço em branco no início da string

```
var a = "['Carro Azul', 'Carro Vermelho', 'ccccc', 'ddddd']";
var array = a.replace(/['\[\]]/g,'').split(',').map(function (str) {
   return str.trim();
});
console.log(array);
```

Answer (score 5):

Apenas mais uma alternativa:

```js
var array = "['aaaaa', 'bbbbb', 'ccccc', 'ddddd']";
array = new Function("return " + array)(); // cria uma função retornando o array e a executa

console.log(array);
```

Dessa forma qualquer que seja o conteúdo do *array*, o parse será feito.

Comment: Isso na prática é o mesmo que `var arr = eval("['aaaaa', 'bbbbb', 'ccccc', 'ddddd']");`

Comment: @Sergio, não deixa de ser verdade, mas eu particularmente prefiro a function.

Answer (score 2):

Você pode utilizar o JSON.parse para resolver isso, mas no formato que está não vai funcionar diretamente, os valores devem estar fechados com aspas duplas.

Nesse caso então você poderia fazer da seguinte forma:

```
//Essa parte converte as aspas simples para aspas duplas
var str = "['aaaaa', 'bbbbb', 'ccccc', 'ddddd']";
str     = str.replace(/\'/g,'"');

//Essa parte converte a string em um objeto
var arr = JSON.parse( str );
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var data = "['aaaaa', 'bbbbb', 'ccccc', 'ddddd']";
var array = data.replace("[","").replace("]","").split(",")
```

Comment: Desta forma o retorno será `array = ['\'aaaaa\'', ' \'bbbbb\'', ' \'ccccc\'', ' \'ddddd\'']`, onde as *string* possuirão espaços em branco e os caracteres `'`, o que não é desejado.

Answer (score 0):

Pode usar o JSON.parse() , porém por padrão os valores strings do json usam " ao invéz de ', isso converteria a string com "

```
var arr = JSON.parse('["aaaaa", "bbbbb", "ccccc", "ddddd"]');
```

Comment: Mudaste a string inicial do AP certo?